# Reset function by button

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I have a button that disappears by a function after one second.
if I click on the button,  I want the function will reset and I will get one another second to click. And-I want the button will disappeared if I did not click this second.
(if I click in a second, the button doesn't disappeared, if I miss one second, it is disappeared, but if I click, I'll get another second, and so on...)

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<button id="btn">click
</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
    btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    click();
    })
    setTimeout(function click() {
        btn.style.display = ('none');
            }, 1000);
```

That code doesn't work.
I am an absolute beginner, so any feedback will help me.

If my question is not understood, please write to me in the comments or edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my suggestion:

```js
var c = 10;
var timer;

clock();

function clock() {
  timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}

function countdown() {
  counter.innerHTML = --c;
  if (c === 0) {
    btn.style.display = 'none';
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}

btn.onclick = function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  c = 10;
  counter.innerHTML = c;
  clock();
};
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me before it's too late (<span id="counter">10</span>)</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can the function start to count ( from 10 to 0) again, on another click? I hope you understand my question.

Comment: You mean just once?

Comment: No.
If I click, it will count again, but if not, he will disappear.
And so on..
If I clicked, it would start counting again, but if not — it would disappear and the game would end. I mean,  as long as I click, it does not disappear and starts counting again. I hope you understand me.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a special reason you prefer to use var in variables?

Comment: You can use ```let``` as well. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var

Answer (score 1):

Change your javascript to the following:

```
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    click();
})

function click() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        btn.style.display = 'none';
    }, 1000);
}
```

Click was not defined properly :)
You should try [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), it'll make your learning a lot easier!
Also press f12 on Google Chrome to show developer console, errors will show up there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `display:none` inside `setTimeout`. Here is an example.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
let time = document.querySelector('#time');
const timeLimit = 10;
let timeoutId, intervalId;

time.innerText = timeLimit;

let startTime;

window.onload = () => {
  startTime = Date.now();
  startTimer();
  removeButton();
}


btn.addEventListener('click', stop);


function stop() {
  intervalId && clearInterval(intervalId);
  timeoutId && clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}


function startTimer() {
  let count = 1;
  
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if(count === 10) clearInterval(intervalId);
  
    time.innerText = timeLimit - count;
    count++;
  }, 1000);
}


function removeButton() {
  timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    btn.style.display = 'none';
  }, timeLimit*1000);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me. I am disappearing ⏳ <span id="time"></span></button>
```

Comment: thanks. I want the button will disappear if I dont click. so what can I do for that?

Comment: @Chanif i've updated the code. Please check now. And please upvote this if you find this helpful.